# "process is not defined" error after react eject

Tags: reactjs, webpack, eslint

After running `yarn eject` in my react project,I get the `'process' is not defined` error when calling `registerServiceWorker()` in *index.js*. files in *scripts* and *config* directories are not modified.

I get the same error for `module` variable.

Comment: I assume you are talking about create-react-app's eject feature. It would be better to share versions.

Comment: Are you talking about actual errors in the console or just ESLint errors?

Comment: What node version are you using? You may need to upgrade it as `process` comes from node. If that's not the case then it may be your webpack or babel configuration that isn't compiling the JS properly.

Comment: what's or OS? windows? because I think after eject you lost some configuration about your `env` so your code doesn't recognize `process`. If your OS is windows I have a good solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because React uses process.env to determine whether you're in a development or production environment. From getting-started.md:

**Note:** by default, React will be in development mode, which is slower, and not advised for production. To use React in production mode, set the environment variable NODE_ENV to production (using envify or webpack's DefinePlugin).

**For example:**

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  "process.env": {
    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production")
  }
});
```

So to build it with Rollup, you need to replace process.env.NODE_ENV with either "**development**" or "**production**" – you can use rollup-plugin-replace for this:

```
rollup({
  entry: 'main.js',
  plugins: [
    replace({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify( 'production' )
    })
  ]
}).then(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is not a lot of details regarding your setup, my answer is going to assume you are using `create-react-app` which is the most common tool with the concept of an `eject` command.

You are using a version of CRA that got released before [this change](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/commit/0e51eef6d7694fbfc4a8fe952bd73b65af2220dd#diff-461785d9e4433f21786632458ee71513), renaming the `registerServiceWorker` file to `serviceWorker` and [disabling SW by default](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2554#issuecomment-358825984), so a version `<=1.1.5` based on release tags.

The Service Worker of CRA is there to cache your assets so that your application still works offline. If you don't need this feature, one straightforward thing to fix the error would be to disable the `registerServiceWorker` call, since that's what they did in the template too.

A more painful one would be to actually upgrade your project to CRA `2.x` but probably worth it in the long run to keep your ejected project as close as possible to the origin. There is an upgrade guide you could take a look at [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v2.0.3).

I myself created a new CRA project using the latest version and ejected it while enabling the service worker and didn't encounter any issue of the sort you are experiencing, so definitely something to consider too.